# Find command not excluding folder from results

Tags: unix, find

I have a shell script which outputs all of the .js and .html files found in a folder provided by the user. I need to exclude a sub-folder and all its files from the search results. I'm using the `find` command to do this. The command I have currently excludes all the files under this sub-folder but outputs the sub-folder in results. I want to exclude a folder called "CrashLog" and all its files. The path to this sub-folder is "Users/test/Desktop/Units/JSunit/CrashLog/"

Here is the find command I'm using:

```
find "Users/test/Desktop/Units" -name CrashLog -prune -o -name "*.html" -o -name "*.js"
```

The output includes "Users/test/Desktop/Units/JSunit/CrashLog/". How can I exclude this? I know I can use grep, but would prefer if there is solution using find itself. I'm running on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `-print`, at the end and parenthesis around the file extension tests:

```
find "Users/test/Desktop/Units" -name CrashLog -prune -o \( -name "*.html" -o -name "*.js" \) -print
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find "Users/test/Desktop/Units" -name CrashLog -prune -a \( -name "*.html" -o -name "*.js" \)
```

Comment: @ DigitalRoss : This doesn't give any output on my Mac.

Comment: In some circumstances, `-print` is implied. I tend to always supply it ... I guess I wasn't being completely retro about that after all ...

Comment: using "-a"  doesn't give any output. Using -o gives an output